# Stuck at remove all in counter app using RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to learn RxJS observables. Wrote a sample app on counters.

- The app has a counter by default
- User can add a new counter , each counter has its own increment, decrement and remove buttons.
- User can remove a counter
- User can see the total of all counters on the page. (**not the number of counters, but the sum of all the counters' values**).

  For eg :

  - There are two counters on the page with values 2,3 respectively. Counters Total should be 2+3 = 5.
  - If counter 1 is removed, counters Total should be 5-2 = 3
- User can remove all the counters at once.

The problem I faced is whenever I click on remove button, it should deduct that counter value from counters total. I used a subject to observe on remove button and it was solved.

Later I added the removeAll button and I am facing the similar problem as before. I cant set the counters total stream to 0.

I tried .last() method but as the observable is not ended, I cant get the last state of counters Total observable.

I used merge() but it doesn't solve the problem.

I couldn't solve it.

I wanted to add a subject again but as I faced this problem twice, now I am wondering if there is better solution than adding a subject? Or I may be missing something.

```

```js
// Code goes here
function createCounter(number){
  return "<div class='counter' id='counter" + number + "'>" +
      '<button id="increment' + number + '">+</button>' + 
      '<h1 style="display:inline-block; margin: 10px" id="counterValue' + number + '"></h1>' + 
      '<button id="decrement' + number + '">-</button>' + 
      '<button id="remove' + number + '">Remove</button>'
    "</div>";
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var addCounter$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#addCounter"), 'click')
  .map(()=> 1)
  .startWith(0)
  .scan((x,y) => x+y);
  
  
  var countersSubject = new Rx.Subject();
  var removeAll$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#removeAll"), 'click').map(() => 0).startWith(0);
  var countersTotal$ = countersSubject.startWith(0).scan((x,y) => x+y).merge(removeAll$);
  
  removeAll$.subscribe(() =>{
    $('#counterContainer').empty();
  });
  
  countersTotal$.subscribe(total => {
    $('#countersTotal').text(total);
  });
  
  
  
  
  addCounter$.subscribe(counterNum => {
    $('#counterContainer').append(createCounter(counterNum));
    
    var increment$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#increment" + counterNum), 'click')
    .map(() => +1);
    var decrement$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#decrement" + counterNum), 'click')
    .map(() => -1);
    var action$ = Rx.Observable.merge(increment$, decrement$);
    
    var state$ = action$.startWith(0).scan((prev, now) => prev+now);
    var counterSubs = state$.subscribe(val => {
      $("#counterValue" + counterNum).text(val);
    });
    
    var countersTotalSubs = action$.subscribe(countersSubject);
    
    var remove$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#remove" + counterNum), 'click');
    var removeCounterTotal$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(remove$, state$, 
    (x,y) => -y);
    removeCounterTotal$.subscribe(countersSubject);
    
    remove$.subscribe(remove => {
      countersTotalSubs.dispose();
      counterSubs.dispose();
      $('div').remove('#counter' + counterNum);
    });
    
  });
  
});
```

See the plunk here. http://plnkr.co/flJx4LNRiboPmW0GjZtl

Please let me know if you need anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you can do it without `Subjects`. I will say this is a rather difficult challenge to take right off the bat (so props to you!), but nonetheless certainly doable.

### **;tldr** see the updated plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dsv40XXEKHmgyjP8LcrK?p=preview)

## Explanation

You've gotten a pretty good start at "everything is a stream" so lets break this down. First, each counter is kind of its own component, it is kind of the amalgamation of several different streams (increment, decrement, remove). So lets start with that and move outward from there.

First off simplify your streams for increment, decrement *and* remove since it is also a behavior:

```
$('#counterContainer').append(createCounter(counterNum));

//The map operator can take a value which it will map to every value it receives
var inc$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#increment' + counterNum), 'click').map(+1);
var dec$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#decrement' + counterNum), 'click').map(-1);
var remove$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#remove' + counterNum), 'click');
```

Next we use the `merge` + `scan` technique to keep a running total of the counter's value.

```
return Rx.Observable.merge(inc$, dec$)
  .startWith(0)
  .scan((prev, now) => prev + now);
```

But now we throw in our first twist, we know that we only want to **take** values **until** the counter is to be removed (notice the emphasis), further, we know that by clicking remove we actually want to remove the counter from the div. By combining these ideas we can add in two new behaviors:

```
return Rx.Observable.merge(inc$, dec$)
  .startWith(0)
  .scan((prev, now) => prev + now)

  //Complete when the remove button is clicked
  .takeUntil(remove$)

  //When completed remove this counter
  .finally(() => $('div').remove('#counter' + counterNum))

  //Show the value
  .do(val => $('#counterValue' + counterNum).text(val));
```

To get all the counters able to run simultaneously we should merge them together, because we actually need two values, a total and a delta value, we will split out two streams, one will be used internally to update the counter's value and the other will be deltas which will be used to update the total value.

In order to do this you can use the `share` and `shareReplay` along with the `using` operator to tie all these streams together.

```
//flatMap has an index parameter which can be used here to tally the total
//number of counters "in-flight"
var counters = addCounter$.flatMap((counterNum, idx) => {

  $('#counterContainer').append(createCounter(counterNum));
  var inc$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#increment' + counterNum), 'click').map(+1);
  var dec$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#decrement' + counterNum), 'click').map(-1);

  //Merges all the events together to describe their logic and then
  //shares the resulting Observable
  var counter = Rx.Observable.merge(inc$, dec$)
    .takeUntil(remove$)
    .startWith(0)
    .share();

  //Creates an Observable that will always emit the last value it
  //recieved to all new subscribers
  var total = counter
    .scan((prev, now) => prev + now, 0)
    .shareReplay(1);

  return Rx.Observable.using(

      //Starts the `total` Observable and updates the counter value
      //when a button is pressed
      //Ties the subscription's lifetime to that of `counter`
      () => total.subscribe(val => $('#counterValue' + counterNum).text(val)), 

      //Returns the counter Observable
      () => counter
  )
    .finally(() => $('div').remove('#counter' + counterNum))
    //When the above Observable completes we will emit one last message
    //which will be the total * -1 (subtracting the value from the overall total)
    .concat(total.last().map(x => x * -1));
});
```

Where `addCounter$` is now defined:

```
var addCounter$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#addCounter"), 'click')

//Map also takes an index parameter which can be leveraged here
.map((_, idx) => idx);
```

Finally we need this to all fit together, the last piece of the puzzle is the `removeAll` capability. All of the stuff we have looked at so far can be thought of as a substream to this functionality, since remove all is sort of like "restoring" state. We can take the `counters` stream and wrap it in a stream that restarts every time the `remove all` is clicked, and because our internal Observables clean up automatically, we will also magically remove them all in the process.

```
var removeAll$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#removeAll"), 'click');

removeAll$
  .startWith(0)
  .flatMapLatest(() => {
    resetTotal();
    //Total all the deltas from all of the counters
    return adder.scan((acc, val) => acc + val);
  })
  .subscribe(x => $('#countersTotal').text(x));
```

And that is all there is to it! See my updated plunkr above with the working example (also copied below).

```js
// Code goes here
function createCounter(number){
  return "<div class='counter' id='counter" + number + "'>" +
  '<button id="increment' + number + '">+</button>' + 
  '<h1 style="display:inline-block; margin: 10px" id="counterValue' + number + '"></h1>' + 
  '<button id="decrement' + number + '">-</button>' + 
  '<button id="remove' + number + '">Remove</button>'
"</div>";
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var addCounter$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#addCounter"), 'click')
  .map((_, idx) => idx);
  
  function resetTotal() {
$('#countersTotal').text(0);
  }
  
  
  var removeAll$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($("#removeAll"), 'click');
  
  var adder = addCounter$.flatMap((counterNum, idx) => {

$('#counterContainer').append(createCounter(counterNum));
var inc$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#increment' + counterNum), 'click').map(+1);
var dec$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#decrement' + counterNum), 'click').map(-1);
var remove$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#remove' + counterNum), 'click');

var counter = Rx.Observable.merge(inc$, dec$)
  .takeUntil(remove$)
  .startWith(0)
  .share();
  
var total = counter
  .scan((prev, now) => prev + now, 0)
  .shareReplay(1);
  
var d = total
  .subscribe(val => $('#counterValue' + counterNum).text(val));

return Rx.Observable.using(() => d, () => counter)
  .finally(() => $('div').remove('#counter' + counterNum))
  .concat(total.last().map(x => x * -1));
  });
  
  
  removeAll$
  .startWith(0)
  .flatMapLatest(() => {
resetTotal();
return adder.scan((acc, val) => acc + val);
  })
  .subscribe(x => $('#countersTotal').text(x));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.0" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="rxjs@4.1.0" data-semver="4.1.0" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.1.0/rx.all.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id ="app">
      
    <button id="addCounter">Add counter</button>
    <button id="removeAll">Remove all</button>
    <h1 >Counters Total <span id="countersTotal" ></span></h1>
    <div id="counterContainer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, flatMap() is new to me and I'll spend sometime on it :). But there is one issue, may be I didn't explain about _countersTotal_ well. So the countersTotal is not the number of counters on the page but the sum of values of all the counters on the page. I have just updated my question with the details. If you can see my original plunk, and see the behavior of countersTotal it would be obvious for you. Thats why I used a stream for countersTotal. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: I updated the solution, passing on the value is slightly more complex, but still quite manageable. I'll update again if I come up with a more succinct solution.

Comment: Awesome :) I will have to learn how it works but thanks for quick answer